# Is it possible to show the content of a googlle drive document on a drupal site?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, google-drive-api

I have a drupal 7 site and i want my google drive content to show up in a page on my site.  I have tried droogle but that only adds links to the files not the files themselves.  Has anyone tried to add google drive content to drupal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module for embedding Google docs in your node via iframes. You can find it [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/gdoc_field). I haven't tested it personally, but it is definitely an interesting idea.

Comment: I cant believe i couldnt find this through searching. Thanks I'll give it a shot